# how to set Ref as a parameter to a Reactive property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

As i am reading about `Additional Ref Unwrapping Details` mentioned in [this link](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#additional-ref-unwrapping-details)
i wanted to implement the below posted example to discenrn the difference between normal `ref` and a `ref` when passed to property of a `reactive` object.

For the below mentioned code,i would like to know the following please:

1-why `console.log("count:",count)` displays an object when `count` is set to 0

2-why `console.log("count:",count)` displays values equal to 1 and 2 when `count` is to 1 and 2 respectively.

3-why  `console.log("state:",state)` diaplays a value equal to the same object for values of `count` is 1,2 and 3

**code**:

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import { ref,reactive } from 'vue'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}
</script>

<script setup>
let count = ref(0)
const state = reactive({count})

console.log("------------count = 0----------------");
console.log("count:",count)
console.log("count.value:",count.value);
console.log("state:",state)
console.log("------------count = 1----------------");
count = 1
console.log("count:",count);
console.log("count.value:",count.value);
console.log("state:",state);
console.log("------------count = 2----------------");
count = 2
console.log("count:",count);
console.log("count.value:",count.value);
console.log("state:",state);
</script>
```

**result**:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the values 1 and 2 to the variable `count`, after which it does not contain a ref anymore, but the value 1 or 2.

So instead of

```
count = 1
```

if you want to keep working with a ref, it should be

```
count.value = 1
```

So instead of overriding the ref, override the ref's value and everything works as expected.

---

In your `state` object, you have assigned the property `count` to the initial ref in the `count` variable. Overriding the variable will not change the value stored in `state`, it still points to the initial ref.